# Bind objects in a Set collection

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form which fills some objects of a Collection. I had the collection implemented with a List (an everything worked good), but now I want to use a Set. I have a property editor registered to create the objects. The problem is that I don't know what is the syntax I must use to populate the objects of the Set.

```
public class MyObject(){
    Set<OtherObject> otherObjects = new HashSet();
}
```

I have tried with the syntax in the form tags, like the syntax a list:

```
name="otherObjects['${status.index}']"
```

and like the syntax for a map:

```
name="otherObjects['${id}']"
```

but both come to an error because "Property referenced in indexed property path 'otherObjects[0]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map"

I have also tried with

```
name="otherObjects"
```

but this doesn't fill the objects.
Can anyone tell me how to bind the data to the objects in a Set.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [documentation on data binding](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html), you can only user the bracket notation to bind to nested objects in a "naturally ordered collection".  A set doesn't qualify.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the old syntax in the form tags and add a getter that will return a set of objects?

```
public class MyObject(){
  List<OtherObject> otherObjectsList = new ArrayList<OtherObjects>();

  public Set<OtherObject> getOtherObject()
  {
    return new HashSet<OtherObject>(otherObjectsList);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is not very clean, it's just a way to avoid to bind to a Set.