# How do I pass an entire model from my Index View to a completely different controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

Here's the relevant part of my Index view (Index.cshtml):

```
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
       <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.name, "Index", "Filler", new { cap = item }, null)
       </li>
    }
```

As you can see, the ActionLink is tied to the Index action on the Filler Controller, and is passing in the entire item (the model)- "item" is of type "capsule".

Now, on my Filler Controller, in the Index action:

```
        public ActionResult Index(capsule cap)
        {
            var fillers = db.fillers.ToList();
            return View(fillers);
        }
```

The capsule class that was automatically generated by Entity Framework is:

```
namespace CapWorx.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class capsule
{
    public capsule()
    {
        this.fillers = new HashSet<filler>();
    }

    public int pk { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<filler> fillers { get; set; }
}
}
```

The problem is "cap" is NULL in the above Index action.  But, if I change the type to "object" instead of "capsule", I do get some weird non-null data, but I can't cast the object to "capsule".  Does anyone know why this is NULL?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: can you share the capsule class?

Comment: I added the capsule class, thanks for reviewing.

Comment: Since the capsule to filler relationship is one to many, I created a ViewModel that has a single capsule object and a list of filler objects.  What I needed was the primary key on the capsule (and also the name of the capsule), and I was trying to pass in the entire object, obviously, and it wasn't working.  So instead I use this ViewModel to do what I need- I'll always have the capsule information as well as the list of fillers for that capsule.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually just have to pass in the `id` to the action. For example, can you refactor your code so that it can take in a `capsuleId`, get the capsule from db and do whatever processing is needed. Adding the entire object to route values in `ActionLink` doesn't make any sense. Have a look at the link being generated. It is probably just something like `...?cap=Namespace.Capsule` as the object would have be `ToString`ed

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is in MVC you can't bind to an interface (`ICollection`).  You'll need to change it to a List - `List<filler>`.  The second problem you will face is that Lists/Arrays need to be represented in array notation for proper posting, something like `name="books[0].book_id"`.  Even though MVC does a lot of magic, the model in your link still has to be represented as a query string eventually.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may be better off representing your model as a JSON object and posting with .ajax().

See this SO post for other ideas - [Need help with binding Set with Spring MVC form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212408/need-help-with-binding-set-with-spring-mvc-form)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not totally sure why this would work(I think you're nulling out the html attributes), but try to remove the "null" part of the actionlink.

Or, the controller which created the models is wrong.

Again, don't kill me for this.

Answer (score -1):

`@Html.ActionLink` just generates an anchor element (`<a href="...">...</a>`), so it makes no sense to attempt to bind a complete object to the `routeValues` parameter. As @manojlds says, it make much more sense to just pass the relevent key value, since you'll be performing the lookup then anyway (remember, the web is "stateless").

Comment: MVC provide the overload to pass a model in ActionLinks and Url helpers and it works well for simple models.

Comment: @viperguynaz I realize you can chose to do so, but like I said, that helper only builds a HTML element, so what is the benefit of doing so? You still have to look data up on the next request, or carry a lot of data over in a querystring.