# How to bind dynamic form fields to a HashSet in Play! with Java?

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, data-binding, playframework

I am fairly new to Play! and I am writing code for a simple dynamic form. I have two model classes: Extension and ExtensionPair. An Extension can contain many ExtensionPairs, so I want to be able to add as many ExtensionPairs as I want and submit the form and bind it to an Extension Java object after it's submitted.

My code works fine when I use an ArrayList for the ExtensionPairs (see code below). However, if I try to use a HashSet instead, I get:

```
[InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'objectExtensionPairs[0]' of bean class
[models.Extension]: Illegal attempt to get property 'objectExtensionPairs' threw
exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException:
Invalid property 'objectExtensionPairs[0]' of bean class [models.Extension]: Cannot
get element with index 0 from Set of size 0, accessed using
property path 'objectExtensionPairs[0]']
```

I was looking for some questions in StackOverflow and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429208/bind-objects-in-a-set-collection) that pretty much says I can't bind a HashSet with Spring Framework.

Are there any alternatives to use a HashSet and form bindings with Play! and Java?

Please see my code below:

**Extension.java:**

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Extension {
    public Extension() {
        objectExtensionPairs = new ArrayList<ExtensionPair>();
    }

    public Extension(String objectExtensionOrganization, String objectExtensionDescription) {
        this();
        this.objectExtensionOrganization = objectExtensionOrganization;
        this.objectExtensionDescription = objectExtensionDescription;
    }

    // Getters and Setters

    private ArrayList<ExtensionPair> objectExtensionPairs;
    private String objectExtensionOrganization;
    private String objectExtensionDescription;
}
```

**ExtensionPair.java:**

```
package models;

public class ExtensionPair {
    public ExtensionPair() {
    }

    public ExtensionPair(String objectExtensionKey, String objectExtensionValue) {
        this.objectExtensionKey = objectExtensionKey;
        this.objectExtensionValue = objectExtensionValue;
    }

    // Getters and Setters

    private String objectExtensionKey;
    private String objectExtensionValue;
}
```

I have coded Play! Java templates for both, so that I can create or edit an Extension using a dynamic form with an "Add" and "Remove" button to have as many ExtensionPairs as I want.

**extensionPairTemplate.scala.html:**

```
@(extP: ExtensionPair, index: Int = 0)

@extensionPair = @{ if(extP == null) new ExtensionPair("","") else extP } 

<script type="text/javascript">
// Some JavaScript code to make the form dynamic (add/remove pairs)
</script>

<div id="epDiv@index.toString()">

objectExtensionKey:
<input type="text" name="objectExtensionPairs[@index.toString()].objectExtensionKey" value="@extensionPair.getObjectExtensionKey()"/>

objectExtensionValue:
<input type="text" name="objectExtensionPairs[@index.toString()].objectExtensionValue" value="@extensionPair.getObjectExtensionValue()" />

<button type="button" id="removeExtensionPairButton@index.toString()" onclick="removeExtensionPairFormElements(@index.toString())">Remove</button>

</div>
```

**extensionTemplate.scala.html:**

```
@(extensionForm: Form[models.Extension], ext: Extension)
@extension = @{ if(ext == null) new Extension("","") else ext } 

<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Some JavaScript code to make the form dynamic (add/remove pairs)
</script>

@helper.form(action = routes.Application.addExtension) {
    <div id="extensionDiv">
    <fieldSet>
        @helper.inputText(extensionForm("objectExtensionOrganization").copy(value=Some(extension.getObjectExtensionOrganization())))
        @helper.inputText(extensionForm("objectExtensionDescription").copy(value=Some(extension.getObjectExtensionDescription())))
        <div id="extensionPairsDiv">
            @if(extension.getObjectExtensionPairs().size() > 0) {
                @for((ep,epIndex) <- extension.getObjectExtensionPairs().zipWithIndex) {
                    @extensionPairTemplate(ep, epIndex)
                }
            }
        </div>
    </fieldSet> 
    <br/>
    <button type="button" id="addPair">Add extension pair</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
}
```

My controller:

```
// For when the form is submitted (i.e. editing an Extension)
public Result addExtension() {
  Form<Extension> formExtension = Form.form(Extension.class).bindFromRequest();
  Extension e = formExtension.get();
  return ok(extensionTemplate.render(Form.form(Extension.class), e));
}

// For when a new Extension is being created
public Result extensionForm() {
    return ok(extensionTemplate.render(Form.form(Extension.class), null));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always bind your form manually:

```
Map<String, String[]> formMap = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
String myContent = formMap.get("myFormElementName")[0]);
```